# Compiling OpenCV with FireWire support on Mac OS 10.6

Tags: macos, opencv, firewire

We have a web-camera and a FireWire camera attached and would like to get input from the second one. But when we use cvCaptureFromCAM(0) and change a number passed as an argument, we're getting data only from a web-camera.

We tried to use OpenCV Private Framework and then it works fine. So, most probably problem is caused by the fact that our OpenCV was not compiled with a support of FireWire. Could you please tell how is it possible to enable that support? Are there any additional libraries needed?

Comment: Probably a better question for Superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you execute **cvCaptureFromCAM**() with **-1** instead of **0**?

Comment: It captures the input from the webcam too.